# How am I getting a "google apps script" error without using google apps scripts?

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine

My site is hosted on appengine in python, but I'm getting an error from google for *client side* ajax requests to a 3rd party APIs. The error page reads as follows:

"Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch. (line 24, file "Code", project "JSON proxy")"

The weird thing is that this happens on multiple 3rd party APIs .. so unless they all happen to be using "google apps scripts" (which I had never heard of, least of all implemented), something strange is going on.

Is google attempting to proxy all my ajax requests? How would I get to the bottom of this anyway?

Comment: its completely unrelated to your appengine. you must have installed an apps script yourself (maybe as a google apps addon). google how to find apps script triggers.

Comment: But I don't even use google apps? I did add my domain/ssl cert directly in the google cloud console .. could that have something to do with it?

Comment: you must have added the apps script, there is no other way. no need for gapps as gmail also can do it.